# how to break installer routine and install program in certain directory

Tags: windows-7, installation

Can I use the command line or other software in Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit to install a program to a specific directory? The supplied installer only installs in the 'Program Files (x86)' directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment yet and don't know of a way to change this with commands or any tool.

You can change the default install directory for Windows in the registry. Follow the instructions in this link [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/48592/how-do-i-change-the-default-program-files-directory-in-windows/). I would recommend changing it back when you are done.

Comment: thank you very much. unfortunately the program does'nt let itself get fooled by you. it landed right in 'program files (x86) again.

Comment: Are you installing with an exe file? You maybe be able to [extract the msi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe) and then [choose the directory to install it to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839978/install-msi-with-msiexec-in-a-specific-directory).

Comment: I've extracted the msi (http://www.pasteall.org/58946) just like you suggested and tried to install then (http://www.pasteall.org/58947). program is beeing installed in 'program files (x86)' again.

Comment: Some people said only the INSTALLDIR version worked for them so maybe try that method. If that doesn't work, here are two other versions to try: [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570242/how-to-change-a-msi-installers-extraction-folder) and [link 2](http://geekswithblogs.net/Compudicted/archive/2009/02/17/forcing-msi-installation-into-a-specific-directory.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot! the version including 'INSTALLDIR' was succesful. I've tried that before but obviously made mistakes. general form of the command I used: http://www.pasteall.org/58957.